# Netbeans build fails "Not copying library" /path/to/${libs.log4j.classpath} , it can't be read

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.2, trying to build a "legacy application" after some updates.

The compile is finishing ok, but then NetBeans is packaging up stuff in `dist/`, and encounters some missing library issues:

```
Copying 1 file to /path/to/Project/build
Not copying library /path/to/Project/${libs.log4j.classpath} , it can't be read.
Not copying library /path/to/Project/${libs.ApacheCommonsCLI.classpath} , it can't be read.
Not copying library /path/to/Project/${libs.BoneCP.classpath} , it can't be read.
```

It refused to copy some other libraries, but these had exact path in the error messages, so I could just put the .JARs where it wanted them.  I have already added some JARs to the source-tree under "Libraries", and this helped the compile succeed. But it doesn't seem to use these for this operation.

How do I provide NetBeans these files?  Where does `${libs...` refer to?

EDIT:  I found that text in a `subfolder/project.properties`:

```
libs.ApacheCommonsNet.classpath=../Apache/Commons/commons-net-1.4.1/commons-net-1.4.1.jar
...
javac.classpath=\
    ${libs.ApacheCommonsNet.classpath}:\
    ${libs.log4j.classpath}:\
    ${libs.ApacheCommonsCLI.classpath}:\
    ${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath}:\
    ${libs.BoneCP.classpath}:\
    ...
```

So it's not complaining about `ApacheCommonsNet` because there is a hard-coded path further up in the properties.  Maybe I can add one for each missing library.

Comment: I looks like the project had some dependencies on libraries stored in other directories.  If those libraries aren't part of your repository, the best would probably to just download them yourself.  Google will help you find them.

Comment: @markspace - I found and downloaded them OK, but I don't know how to get NetBeans to use them.

Comment: That's actually a good question since this is a legacy app.  The best way would be to start by inspecting the build.xml file (or whatever build system you're using) and find these references there.  Figure out what the build system expects then decide how best to fit them into the legacy app.  If you can, consult with coworkers about the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved by configuring NetBeans Libraries under `[Tools]`->`[Libraries]`.

To resolve say the `${libs.ApacheCommonsCLI.classpath}` dependency, I added a library named "ApacheCommonsCLI", then for that entry added the JAR "commons-cli-1.2.jar" via the button `[Add JAR/Folder...]`.

The dependency starting with the test `${libs.` is an indicator that it is looking for it here.

Answer (score 1):

Right-clicking the libraries folder -> choosing the properties window -> deleting the libraries that i deleted before, becuase i moved all of them in one library, helped me.